# Uploading Multiple CSV into mysql using PHP

Tags: php

I got this code for importing multiple csv file into database but when i tried to upload only one file is being uploaded. I tried many things but just couldn't find a way.

```
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple /><br />
    </div><!-- ./col -->
    <input type="submit"  class="form-control"name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    { 
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        fgetcsv($handle);
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $ITEM_CODE_MX =$filesop[1];
            $addqtyqry = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO salesreceiptlinedetail
                        (ItemRef_FullName)
                VALUES ('".$ITEM_CODE_MX."')");
            $c = $c + 1;
        }       
    }
?>
```

Comment: First some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I don't know much PHP but usually there is a Do until EOF (end of file) loop pointed at a particular folder to achieve what you are after in other languages.  That would be wrapped around your current code or you could conditionally AND <> EOF (!= EOF) to your id submit is set conditional.  I don't see where this code block would repeat other than if submit is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowing multiple files so you need to loop over these multiple file references in the `$_FILES` array.

> Your script was also open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   So I used a prepared and parameterised query [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Preparing the statement once and executing it multiple times is one of the ways you can leverage prepared statements to save you execution time.

```
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple /><br />
    </div><!-- ./col -->
    <input type="submit"  class="form-control"name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

    include ("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
        //prepare the insert before you start looping
        $ins_stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO salesreceiptlinedetail
                                    (ItemRef_FullName) VALUES(?)';

        // check the prepare worked and the the query is correctly coded
        if (FALSE === $ins_stmt) {
            echo 'Error: '.$link->error;
            exit;
        }

        foreach ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $file ) {

            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $c = 0;

            // read and ignore headers
            fgetcsv($handle);


            while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== false) {

                $ins_stmt->bind_param('s', $filesop[1]);
                $ins_stmt->execute();
                $c++;
            }       
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: when i submitted the form it just loading for longtime and data doesn't insert i tried two csv with 3 row each

Comment: See added code under the comment `// while testing add some error reporting` See if that gives us a clue :)

Comment: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given   This error is flooded l

Comment: Undefined index: tmp_name

Comment: Sorry, need more coffee, I got my loop wrong. See the changed foreach loop

Comment: Ok, added a check to see if the `prepare` failed for some reason. Try that

Comment: Add an `echo $filesop[1] . '<br>';` to see if we are reading the csv file or not after `while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== false) {`

Comment: but doesn't import